# Binary Message -> Text

Tags: websocket, binary, decode

Websocket возвращает информацию, которая выглядит как сжатый файл в формате GZIP, что подтверждается последовательностью байтов \x1f\x8b\x08.

```
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x035\xce\xb1\r\xc20\x14E\xd1\xfb\xfc\xbfm\x08\x10E\x08\t\xa5a\x02W)Y!\x12\x1d\x13\xc0\x12L\xc0<\xd9"\xb3\x90\x96\x01\x88\x0b\xf4\x8a\xdb\x9c\xe2\xbd@o\xc4\x83xn\xf5U(\xb2"\x9f\x89O\xd2@.\xda\x0cl/4\'v\r{8@\x0b&\x1c\x085Y\x9fu\xa1\xf7\xde\xad\xa3\xc3\'\x9b,^\xb9y\x82\xa3g\xb8\xbb\xf8\xb3E\x8b\xacZ\xaf6V\x9b\xb4\x1e\xc8\xa3\x8f\xfe\x03Iq)b\x8e\x00\x00\x00'
```

После декомпрессии информация выглядит следующим образом.

```
b'y\x00\x00\x01\x87\x00\x01\x00c\x00\x05\x17\x0e\x01\xf4\x01\x02,\x01\x03,\x01\x04\xc8\x00\x05d\x00\x062\x00\x07,\x01\x082\x00\t\x1e\x00\n\x14\x00\x0b\n\x00\x0c\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x03\x01\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x02\x01\x00\x04\x00\x07\x01\xea\x01\xea\x01\x02\x19\x04\x19\x04\x03\x10\x00\x10\x00\x04\xb1\x03\xb1\x03\x05:\x00N\x04\x06\x00\x00\x12\x04\x07\x00\x00U\x04\x01\x00\x00\x07\x01\xea\x01\xea\x01\x02\xeb\x01\xeb\x01\x03\x19\x04\x19\x04\x04\x10\x00\x10\x00\x05\xb1\x03\xb1\x03\x06\x01\x00\x01\x00\x07K\x04K\x04'
```

Какие могут быть дальнейшие шаги? Есть код на JS, в котором каким-то образом обрабатывается данная информация, но разобрать не смог.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PN6cvMGCDnNDkgK97Bcnn8JbH6yEBnYf/view?usp=sharing